# Make [mac-os-x-server] a synonym of [osx-server]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

The tags [mac-os-x-server](/questions/tagged/mac-os-x-server) and [osx-server](/questions/tagged/osx-server) both refer to the same operating system. I suggest that [mac-os-x-server](/questions/tagged/mac-os-x-server) is made a synonym [osx-server](/questions/tagged/osx-server) to fit the pattern of [all the other osx tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx-lion+or+osx-mountain-lion+or+osx-snow-leopard+or+osx-mavericks+or+osx-leopard+or+osx-server+or+osx-gatekeeper+or+osx-tiger+or+osx-10.9+or+osx-chameleon).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[OK.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/osx-server/synonyms)